# Cors problem with nestjs in centos 7 local machine

Tags: node.js, cors, nestjs

Hi I have a FE react app and a BE nest.js app running on the same centos 7 virtual machine, my problem is that I can't make the rest calls from FE to BE due to the error reported under the thing that seems to me strange is that on my local machine, ubuntu there is no cors error, what is this due to? how can i fix it? i have to edit axios

*Error:*

```
Multi-origin request blocked (cross-origin): the origin match criterion does not allow the remote resource to be read from http: // localhost: 3001 / user. Reason: CORS request failed. Status code: (null)
```

**Nest.js code:**

```
import { ValidationPipe } from "@nestjs/common";
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { SwaggerModule, DocumentBuilder } from "@nestjs/swagger";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import * as cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    cors: true,
  });
  const config = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle("Backend ")
    .setDescription("Api Backend")
    .setVersion("1.0")
    .addTag("Backend")
    .addBearerAuth(
      { type: "http", scheme: "bearer", bearerFormat: "JWT" },
      "access-token"
    )
    .build();
  //Setup swagger module
  var options = {
    deepScanRoutes: true,
  };
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup("api", app, document);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  //Enable cors
  app.enableCors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3001","http://localhost:3006", "http://80.211.128.77:3001","http://memoryp.org:3006"],
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
  });
  await app.listen(3001);
}

bootstrap();
```